# Ruby on Rails and phone interception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, telephony

I have a simple RoR application with PostgreSQL database. It is a call-center program and operators should identify customer by phone number.

What I want:
Intercept incoming call (mobile, non-mobile), identify phone number, compare identified number with my database and if there is a customer with such number - show all his data on screen.

Questions:
1. How to intercept incoming call with my computer or server?
2. How can I identify phone number?
3. How can I inject accepted phone number to my database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are creating a call center service, with voip/SIP you can't intercept anything.
If you are using some pbx software, like asterisk wich use SIP protocol, you need to look at contact header.

You can also use a cloud communications provider like twillio or plivo which provides an opensource alternative to twillio.

Comment: So, I need some hardware like this? http://www.digium.com/en/products/telephony-cards